# Operator Overloading (addition) for dynamic 2D array

Tags: c++

So I've been working a problem the last few hours and just can't seem to stop my program from crashing. The problem is to create program that takes a matrix of any size and is able to add one to another using operator overloading. My program is crashing right when I try to add two objects of my class. Any help is GREATLY appreciated! I apologize for the large amount of code but I figured you guys may need to see my constructors/value handling and I'm at a bit of a loss with this problem here so it's my last resort.

Class:

```
#ifndef matrixType_H
#define matrixType_H

class matrixType
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& osObject, const matrixType& cObject);

public:
    void setValue();
    matrixType operator+(const matrixType& object)const;
    matrixType operator-(const matrixType& object)const;
    matrixType operator*(const matrixType& object)const;
    const matrixType& operator=(const matrixType& object);
    matrixType();
    matrixType(const matrixType& object);
    matrixType(int, int);
    ~matrixType();

private:
    int row;
    int col;
    int **matrixPointer1;
};

#endif
```

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrixType.h"
using namespace std;

void matrixType::setValue()
{
    int **matrixPointer1 = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        matrixPointer1[i] = new int[col];

    cout << "Enter each element of the matrix: " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            cin >> matrixPointer1[i][j];
        }
    }
}

matrixType matrixType::operator+(const matrixType& object)const
{
    matrixType temp(row, col);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            temp.matrixPointer1[i][j] = matrixPointer1[i][j] + object.matrixPointer1[i][j];
        }
    } 

    return temp;
}

matrixType::matrixType(const matrixType& object)
{
    row = object.row;
    col = object.col;

    int **matrixPointer1 = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        matrixPointer1[i] = new int[col];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            matrixPointer1[i][j] = object.matrixPointer1[i][j];
        }
    }

}

const matrixType& matrixType::operator=(const matrixType& object)
{
    row = object.row;
    col = object.col;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            matrixPointer1[i][j] = object.matrixPointer1[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const matrixType& cObject)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cObject.row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cObject.col; j++){
            osObject << cObject.matrixPointer1[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return osObject;
}

matrixType::matrixType(int r, int c)
{
    row = r;
    col = c;

    int **matrixPointer1 = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        matrixPointer1[i] = new int[col];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            matrixPointer1[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

matrixType::~matrixType()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        delete[]matrixPointer1[i];
    }

    delete[]matrixPointer1;
}
```

Part of the source:

```
cout << "Enter the number of rows in matrix one: ";
cin >> rows1;

cout << "Enter the number of columns in matrix one: ";
cin >> cols1;

cout << "Enter the number of rows in matrix two: ";
cin >> rows2;

cout << "Enter the number of columns in matrix two: ";
cin >> cols2;

matrixType matrix1(rows1, cols1);
matrixType matrix2(rows2, cols2);
matrixType matrix3(rows1, cols1);

matrix1.setValue();
matrix2.setValue();

cout << "Which operation would you like to perform? (+, -, *): ";
cin >> operation;

if (operation == "+"){
    if (rows1 == rows2 && cols1 == cols2){
        matrix3 = matrix1 + matrix2; //crashes when the + operator function is called
        cout << matrix3; //The << operator also causes a crash when tried by itself
    }

    else
        cout << "Error: Matrix sizes are not equal." << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's kind of off topic, but how do you meaningfully add two matrices with different size?

Comment: It is off topic as well, but if you want to do serious linear algebra check out this library http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At no point you're initializing the member `int **matrixPointer1`, you're just creating a local one. Change this:

```
int **matrixPointer1 = new int*[row];
```

to this (in constructor, copy constructor, `setValue`):

```
matrixPointer1 = new int*[row];
```

You also aren't doing any reallocation in `operator=` and it requires the two `matrixType`s to have same `row` and `col` count, is that what you want? Also, `setValue` will then leak the previously allocated memory.

Comment: You're welcome. Remarked by the other comment, you should rather have class template for this, if that's possible.